# How can I slice array multidimension?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**My output array like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [3] => 0.24022657034509
            [0] => 0.31039543711844
            [2] => 0.6270142808618
            [1] => 0.75379703175047
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0.056067176666841
            [0] => 0.57560961693454
            [3] => 0.72174392391777
            [2] => 0.76119762242023
        )
    )
```

I just want to delete all element in array except 3 element in above, and I want the index not reset.
I've tried use array slice but still failed.
Thanks..

**I want to get output like this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [3] => 0.24022657034509
            [0] => 0.31039543711844
            [2] => 0.6270142808618

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0.056067176666841
            [0] => 0.57560961693454
            [3] => 0.72174392391777

        )
    )
```

**Here my code **

```
$hasil_jarak=array();
        for ($i=0; $i <count($fitur1_uji) ; $i++) {
            $temp=array();
            for ($j=0; $j <count($fitur1_latih) ; $j++) { 
                $euclid=sqrt(
                    (pow($fitur1_uji[$i]-$fitur1_latih[$j],2))+
                    (pow($fitur2_uji[$i]-$fitur2_latih[$j],2))+
                    (pow($fitur3_uji[$i]-$fitur3_latih[$j],2))+
                    (pow($fitur4_uji[$i]-$fitur4_latih[$j],2))+
                    (pow($fitur5_uji[$i]-$fitur5_latih[$j],2))+
                    (pow($fitur6_uji[$i]-$fitur6_latih[$j],2)));
                    array_push($temp, $euclid);
            }
            array_push($hasil_jarak, $temp);
        }
        $hasil_jarak=array_map(function($v){asort($v); return $v;}, $hasil_jarak); 
        return $hasil_jarak;
```

Comment: We need to see your codes

Comment: Uh, `array_column` should work. https://secure.php.net/array_column

Comment: can u give me example about it ?@CharlotteDunois

Comment: @u_mulder, this is my code : <br>
 ` $hasil_jarak=array();
  for ($i=0; $i <count($fitur1_uji) ; $i++) {
   $temp=array();
   for ($j=0; $j <count($fitur1_latih) ; $j++) { 
    $euclid=sqrt(
     (pow($fitur1_uji[$i]-$fitur1_latih[$j],2)));
     array_push($temp, $euclid);
   }
   array_push($hasil_jarak, $temp);
  }
  $hasil_jarak=array_map(function($v){asort($v); return $v;}, $hasil_jarak); 
  return $hasil_jarak;`

Comment: Edit you question please https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44155933/edit

Answer (score 1):

To get n first elements of array use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$arr = [
    [
        3 => 1,
        0 => 2,
        4 => 4,
        1 => 5,
        2 => 8,
    ],
    [
        2 => 1,
        1 => 4,
        0 => 7,
        3 => 9,
        4 => 11,
    ],
];
$new_array = [];  // new array
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $new_array[] = array_slice($item, 0, 3);   // 3 is a size of new subarray
    // or with preserving keys:
    $new_array[] = array_slice($item, 0, 3, true);   // 3 is a size of new subarray
}
```

Comment: the result of your code was reset the index of array @u_mulder

Comment: Fourth parameter of `array_slice` is `preserve_keys`. Set it to `true`.

Comment: yes its can help me to solve my problem.. thanks.., I will try to implemented in my code. @u_mulder